# How to make this DIV scroll down ONLY to end of its section?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Consider the code below:

What I need to do is to have `<div class="col-lg-12 kip">` and all it's content scroll down only to the end of section workOne and NOTHING BEYOND THAT ..

I have attached an image here that will show you what happens now to this fixed div,
as you can see in the image, it leave its section and goes beyond the button / what I need to do is that have it stop and the end of the section or RIGHT ABOVE THE BUTTON.

**How can I do this either in CSS or JS / please be detailed as much as you can because as a beginner I may need illustration.**

[IMAGE TO SHOW THE ISSUE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iyix.jpg)

```
<section id="workOne">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">


 <!-- #### DIV CLASS "kip" is what need to be fixed and scroll down to end of this section#### -->

                <div class="col-lg-12 kip">
                    <h2>Kipeesh Language Check // Version 1.0</h2>
                    <p>Client asked to develop a simple language learning app.</p>
                    <ul class="kipul">
                        <li>Development in progress</li>
                        <li>Will be made to fit Wordpress</li>
                        <li><mark>html</mark>&nbsp;&nbsp;<mark>css</mark>&nbsp;&nbsp;<mark>javascript</mark>&nbsp;&nbsp;<mark>php</mark></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>


                <!-- #### ONE #### -->

                <div class="col-lg-6">
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6  kip2">
                    <p>01. Overview</p>
                    <img src="assets/images/kip1.jpg">

                </div>

                <!-- #### TWO #### -->


                <div class="col-lg-6">
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6  kip2">
                    <p>02. Create a button to hide elements.</p>
                    <img src="assets/images/kip2.jpg">
                </div>


                <!-- #### THREE #### -->

                <div class="col-lg-6">
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6  kip2">

                    <p>03. Put the button to work / hide elements</p>
                    <img src="assets/images/kip3.jpg">
                </div>


                <!-- #### FOUR #### -->

                <div class="col-lg-6">
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6  kip2">
                    <p>04. Add a reveal button to display one item at a time</p>

                    <img src="assets/images/kip4.jpg">

                </div>

                <a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="popup('https://moenagy.dev/Kipeesh')"><button type="button" class="btn btnWork btn-outline-light btn-lg">View Version 1.0</button></a>



            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

 <!-- #### DIV CLASS "kip" must end here and and scroll down further to the next section #### -->
```

Comment: Hi! Are you able to create a jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/) for this?

Comment: @kunambi One is required to produce a [mcve] here, **within his question**. Putting it into a jsfiddle may get this question closed.

Comment: Is this bootstrap? If so, you need to tag it.

Comment: I'm using bootstrap for the layout yes, can you clarify on what u mean with code ?

Comment: The other person asked you to put your code into a jsfiddle. But you are required to post a [mcve] here. If that code you show here does not reproduce the problem, then your question will be closed, even if you post it on a jsfiddle or any other third party site.

Answer (score 0):

Done, fixed with the following:

```
.kip{
    position: sticky;
    top: 50%;
    }
```